# How can i compile C programs with Makefile on ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile, compilation

I am trying to compile some programs i have found on github. The repository is at the following URL:
[enter link description here][1]

https://github.com/iagox86/nbtool

I have little knowledge of C programs, however when i try to use GCC with the following command i receive errors.
the command i have tried is:

```
gcc -o dnslogger dnslogger.c
```

I receive the following error:

```
/tmp/ccLRFQbp.o: In function `dns_callback':
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `dns_create_from_packet'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `dns_create'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `dns_add_question'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `dns_add_answer_A'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x1dc): undefined reference to `dns_add_answer_AAAA'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `dns_to_packet'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x236): undefined reference to `udp_send'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `dns_create_error_string'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x282): undefined reference to `udp_send'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x28e): undefined reference to `safe_free'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x29a): undefined reference to `dns_destroy'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x2a6): undefined reference to `dns_destroy'
/tmp/ccLRFQbp.o: In function `dns_poll':
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x2d7): undefined reference to `select_group_create'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x304): undefined reference to `select_group_add_socket'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `select_set_recv'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x336): undefined reference to `select_group_do_select'
/tmp/ccLRFQbp.o: In function `cleanup':
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x36b): undefined reference to `select_group_destroy'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x37a): undefined reference to `safe_free'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x384): undefined reference to `print_memory'
/tmp/ccLRFQbp.o: In function `main':
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x6ed): undefined reference to `safe_malloc_internal'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x718): undefined reference to `winsock_initialize'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0x934): undefined reference to `dns_do_test'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0xaab): undefined reference to `udp_create_socket'
dnslogger.c:(.text+0xb5f): undefined reference to `drop_privileges'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the repository has a Makefile file which i suspect is used to compile the programs, but i am not sure of the exact commands to use on ubuntu, i have tried some of the commands but i receive errors when using the supplied commands from the file.
the makefile is located here:

https://github.com/iagox86/nbtool/blob/master/Makefile

How can i compile these programs from ubuntu command line?

Comment: In general (and as is clear in the Makefile you linked to), doing a 'make all' from terminal is the standard for compiling C programs. Have you tried that?

Comment: The `makefile` you link to has the rule `dnslogger: dnslogger.o buffer.o tcp.o udp.o select_group.o types.o memory.o dns.o` — `${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o dnslogger dnslogger.o buffer.o tcp.o udp.o select_group.o types.o memory.o dns.o ${LIBS}` for building `dnslogger`.  Your command line is missing almost all of the object files.

Comment: You say "I receive errors when using the supplied commands from the file".  What file do you mean?  The makefile?  How are you "using" those commands?  Are you trying to execute them yourself?  You shouldn't do that: a makefile is intended to be used by the `make` program so you should run `make`.  If you are getting errors when trying to run `make`, please show those errors then we can help you.  Compiling a program is a complicated process, that's why makefiles exist in the first place.  Just running a compile command directly is unlikely to work except in the simplest cases.

Comment: This should be a good place to start - https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html#using

Answer (score 2):

Just run `make`.

```
git clone https://github.com/iagox86/nbtool
cd nbtool
make
```

You need some programs to compile everything (samples) though.
(make will complain if they're missing on your system)

If you're more interested in the Makefile itself, use the links in the comments or read specific documentation for example [Gnu Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)
(I chose Gnu Make, as tags specify ubuntu explicitly)